# Ubuntu 15.10 Live USB not starting due to graphic card driver errors (nouveau)

Tags: nouveau

The desktop is not starting at all. So I cannot install the proprietary drivers for NVidia via system preferences. Any advice please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from the Ubuntu installation media and select Try Ubuntu without installing.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Live desktop - now install Ubuntu.

After it is  finished, reboot the system and this time select the Ubuntu menu entry.
Press the <kbd>E</kbd> key and add `nouveau.modeset=0` at the end of the `linux` line.
Set a <kbd>Space</kbd> between the last character in the `linux` line and `nouveau.modeset=0`
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into Ubuntu - now install the NVIDIA drivers.

Reboot the system, now you don't have to add the parameter any more.